# When I deploy LAMP Stack on Google Cloud Platform the deployment shows these warnings. How to fix this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lamp

When I deploy LAMP Stack in Google cloud platform this warnings show after finished the deployment.

> This deployment has resources from the Runtime Configurator service,
> which is in Beta. There is no planned date for moving this feature
> into General Availability (GA). Examples of runtimeconfig types used:
> runtimeconfig.v1beta1.config, runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter

[image]

How can avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of how you deployed this? Marketplace apps you used or code you used to deploy this?

Comment: I used LAMP Stack in Marketplace

Answer (score 1):

As the warning message states that the feature that you would like to use is not completely available yet and there is no planned date as well and to confirm this I have tried creating the same deployment in my test environment and I even ended up with the same warning message even after it was deployed.

The warning was an intended behavior and made to notify that the product you are trying to use [Run time Configurator](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator) is still at Pre-GA offerings hence not to rely completely on it. If you want to continue the usage of the respective deployments using Run time Configurator you can ignore the default warning messages.